# JQuery send vars generated in loop by post

Tags: jquery, loops, post

I need some help with this, hope you can make me see the light.

I'm generating a data string whithin a loop:

```
var cadena_post_a_enviar = '';
var n = datos_cookie.length;
$.each(datos_cookie,function(key, value) {


        var post_txt_nombre = 'nombre'+datos_cookie[key]['id'];
        var post_val_nombre = datos_cookie[key]['id'];

        var post_txt_cantidad = 'cantidad'+datos_cookie[key]['id'];
        var post_val_cantidad = datos_cookie[key]['cantidad'];

        var post_txt_cantidadfuera = 'cantidadfuera'+datos_cookie[key]['id'];
        var post_val_cantidadfuera = datos_cookie[key]['cantidadfuera'];

        var post_txt_precio_de_venta = 'precio_de_venta'+datos_cookie[key]['id'];
        var post_val_precio_de_venta = datos_cookie[key]['precio_de_venta'];

        var post_txt_porcentaje = 'porcentaje'+datos_cookie[key]['id'];
        var post_val_porcentaje = datos_cookie[key]['porcentaje'];

        var post_txt_observ = 'observ'+datos_cookie[key]['id'];
        var post_val_observ = datos_cookie[key]['observ'];

        var post_txt_tipo_unidad_compra = 'tipo_unidad_compra'+datos_cookie[key]['id'];
        var post_val_tipo_unidad_compra = datos_cookie[key]['tipo_unidad_compra'];

        var post_txt_tipo = 'tipo'+datos_cookie[key]['id'];
        var post_val_tipo = datos_cookie[key]['id'];

        var post_txt_empfactu = 'empfactu'+datos_cookie[key]['id'];
        var post_val_empfactu = datos_cookie[key]['empfactu'];


        if (key == n-1)
            cadena_post_a_enviar += post_txt_nombre + ': "' + post_val_nombre +'", ' + post_txt_cantidad +': "' + post_val_cantidad + '", ' + post_txt_cantidadfuera + ': "' + post_val_cantidadfuera + '", ' + post_txt_precio_de_venta + ': "' + post_val_precio_de_venta +'", ' + post_txt_porcentaje + ': "' + post_val_porcentaje + '", ' + post_txt_observ + ': "' + post_val_observ + '", ' + post_txt_tipo_unidad_compra + ': "' + post_val_tipo_unidad_compra + '", ' + post_txt_tipo + ': "' +  post_val_tipo + '", ' + post_txt_empfactu + ': "' + post_val_empfactu + '" ';
         else
            cadena_post_a_enviar += post_txt_nombre + ': "' + post_val_nombre +'", ' + post_txt_cantidad +': "' + post_val_cantidad + '", ' + post_txt_cantidadfuera + ': "' + post_val_cantidadfuera + '", ' + post_txt_precio_de_venta + ': "' + post_val_precio_de_venta +'", ' + post_txt_porcentaje + ': "' + post_val_porcentaje + '", ' + post_txt_observ + ': "' + post_val_observ + '", ' + post_txt_tipo_unidad_compra + ': "' + post_val_tipo_unidad_compra + '", ' + post_txt_tipo + ': "' +  post_val_tipo + '", ' + post_txt_empfactu + ': "' + post_val_empfactu + '", ';



    });
```

So with this code i get the var cadena_post_a_enviar with this value:

```
ombre25: "25", cantidad25: "", cantidadfuera25: "53", precio_de_venta25: "12.05", porcentaje25: "", observ25: "U", tipo_unidad_compra25: "undefined", tipo25: "25", empfactu25: "1", nombre301: "301", cantidad301: "", cantidadfuera301: "53", precio_de_venta301: "2.49", porcentaje301: "", observ301: "U", tipo_unidad_compra301: "C", tipo301: "301", empfactu301: "1"
```

And finally i send this string by post method (For me its the same if sended by post or ajax, i'm going to redirect after post sent)

```
$.ajax({
        url : 'televending-carrito-proceso.php?insertar=historico',
        data : cadena_post_a_enviar,
        type : 'POST',
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

The problem is that variables are not being sent by post. Here are the firebug post sent values:

nombre25: "25", cantidad25: "", cantidadfuera25: "53", precio_de_venta25: "12.05", porcentaje25: "", observ25: "U", tipo_unidad_compra25: "undefined", tipo25: "25", empfactu25: "1", nombre301: "301", cantidad301: "", cantidadfuera301: "53", precio_de_venta301: "2.49", porcentaje301: "", observ301: "U", tipo_unidad_compra301: "C", tipo301: "301", empfactu301: "1"

Thnx for your help!

Comment: These seem to be exact identical values.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have it.

The only way to send post vars as string is to format them as if they were posted by GET method.

```
    cadena_post_a_enviar += '&articulos[]=' + post_val_nombre + '&' + post_txt_nombre + '=' + post_val_nombre +'&' + post_txt_cantidad +'=' + post_val_cantidad + '&' + post_txt_cantidadfuera + '=' + post_val_cantidadfuera + '&' + post_txt_precio_de_venta + '=' + post_val_precio_de_venta +'&' + post_txt_porcentaje + '=' + post_val_porcentaje + '&' + post_txt_observ + '=' + post_val_observ + '&' + post_txt_tipo_unidad_compra + '=' + post_val_tipo_unidad_compra + '&' + post_txt_tipo + '=' +  post_val_tipo + '&' + post_txt_empfactu + '=' + post_val_empfactu + '&' + post_txt_bajo_pedido + '=' + post_val_bajo_pedido  + '&' + post_txt_cant_anterior + '=' + post_val_cant_anterior  + '&' + post_txt_precio_tarifa + '=' + post_val_precio_tarifa;
```

Hope it helps to someone!